# Convert .wav audio file to text c#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to convert .wav audio file to byte and then convert this byte array to string.
I do this using c# but the string it return is not in valid format i.e. not in readable form.
How can i get the string in readable format?

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("SomeAudio.wav");
string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

In result the data is not readable i.e. it returns `���걄�`

Comment: Share some code!

Comment: What on earth are you asking? What are you looking to achieve? *"the string it return is not in valid format i.e. not in readable form..."* <- what do you mean by this? It's not like converting the byte array to a string is going to give you the lyrics to the song...

Comment: var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("SomeAudio.wav");
string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
In result the data is not readable i.e. it returns ���걄�

Comment: @FarooqAwan you can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/44095769/edit) your question. That will make it easier for people to see. I'll do it for you this time. That doesn't explain what do you want anyway.

Comment: Do you know the concept of binary files? Feels like you're expecting `.wav` to be a text file.

Comment: In all honesty [it should result in](http://www.topherlee.com/software/pcm-tut-wavformat.html): `RIFF` + something "not readable" + `WAVEfmt` + more "not readable" stuff + `data` + even more "not readable" stuff. Is that what you want? Perhaps you don't have a valid `.wav` file. What are the chances that it is a file of another format with the wrong extension? (It doesn't look like `mp3` either).

Comment: No,  the audio file is in correct format and understandable.

Comment: Do you need [Speech recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_recognition)? If so, try [Speech recognition, speech to text, text to speech, and speech synthesis in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/483347/speech-recognition-speech-to-text-text-to-speech-a) - You have me guessing what you want. If what you wan't isn't speech recognition either... Can you share the expected result? Perhaps the audio too?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII` instead

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("SomeAudio.wav");
string result = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
```

and for write some sample you can use

```
FileStream f = new FileStream("a.wav", FileMode.Create);
BinaryWriter wr = new BinaryWriter(f);
wr.Write(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("RIFF"));
```

Comment: No it will also return RIFF??
I mean it return some bug or \0\0\0\0|????\0?0

Comment: @FarooqAwan What do you expect it to return?

Comment: @Ryan I gave you point (+1) I don`t understand why you get and also me minus points.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create blob here is good example "MSSQL" later you can put blob to table in database.

```
DECLARE @BLOB varbinary(MAX)
SET @BLOB = (SELECT * 
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\AAAAAAA\Desktop\master\templates\miusic.wav', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB)

SELECT @BLOB
```